# trigger prompt's ok button programmatically

Tags: javascript

is it possible to tigger confirm dialog **ok** button click event by js code?

Please let me know any way to do it.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to bypass all confirm dialogs for a given page, just run `window.confirm = function(){return true;};`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. Why bother having a confirmation prompt if you're going to bypass it?